# Counting problem (combination). How many ways to create 2 indistinguishable piles from 21 identical elements.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

You have 21 identical elements, let's say books. How many ways to place the books into 2 indistinguishable piles? (This means that putting 16 books in the first pile and 5 books in the second is the same as 5 books in the first pile and 16 books in the second)

Comment: The sizes of the piles are the only things that matter. What are the possible combinations of sizes? They’re easy to list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be paraphrased like this: X+Y=21 (and I assume that either X or Y can be zero)

Visualized it like this:

```
********|************* = 8+13=21
****************|*****
*|********************
```

You get [Stars And Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) where:

$$
{\binom{n+k-1}{n}}
$$

Since you wish to have distinguishable result you divide by 2 hence: $$
{\frac{\binom{21+2-1}{21}}2}
 = 11 $$

As a side note, you can also count them:

```
X    Y   
0   21  21
1   20  21
2   19  21
3   18  21
4   17  21
5   16  21
6   15  21
7   14  21
8   13  21
9   12  21
10  11  21

11  10  21 Repetition 
12  9   21
13  8   21
14  7   21
15  6   21
16  5   21
17  4   21
18  3   21
19  2   21
20  1   21
21  0   21
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the formula "n+k-1...", where did you get the "-1"? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say there are $F$ books in the first pile and $S$ books in the second pile

$$F+S=21$$

$$F=21-S$$

Since $F,S \geq 1$,
for each $S,1\leq S\leq 20 $  there is a  corresponding $F$ pile.

This gives $20$ solutions.
But each case was overcounted twice.

Hence there are a total of $10$ ways